# close listener or listener in HttpRequest

Tags: dart

I saw with nodejs it's possible to add a listener on a request :

```
req.addListener('close', .... );
```

But I cant't find how to deal with Dart.
My need is to cancel a timer which send data using SourceEvent. If a don't cancel it, it keep running when the client disconnect.

Edit : I add my use case

```
_time(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
  response.headers..set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 'text/event-stream')
              ..set(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, 'no-cache')
              ..set(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, 'keep-alive');
  var timer = new Timer.repeating(1000, (_){
    Date now = new Date.now();
    response.outputStream..writeString('data:${now.millisecondsSinceEpoch}\n\n');
  });
  // Here what I want to do
  request.onClose((event) => timer.cancel();  
}
```

My request is a classic http request call by my request handler on url "/time". I use SourceEvent to push time to client and it works fine.
But I need detect when the client close his connexion. After searching, how to do it found many samples with nodejs witch use this `req.addListener('close', ... )`

Answer (score 0):

You can add event handlers to the [HttpClientConnection](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_io/HttpClientConnection.html) and to the response/requests data stream. Like this:

```
var conn = httpClient.get(host, port, path);
conn.onResponse = (HttpClientResponse response) {
  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    StringInputStream stream = new StringInputStream(response.inputStream);
    StringBuffer body = new StringBuffer();
    stream.onData = () => body.add(stream.read());
    stream.onClosed = () {
      // do something when its closed
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think I can't adapt this samples with my need. I edit my question to be more precise on my problem.

Comment: @NicolasFrançois ahh now I see what it is you want to do, I have not found a way to do this with Dart. Perhaps you should open a bug

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but the best I can think of is to use the inputStream:

```
request.inputStread.onClosed((_) => timer.cancel());
```

I agree with Lars though, even if that works it should be easier to find and more explicit. Might want to file a bug.

Comment: It try it, but not works : the timer is cancel before response starts. I open a issue on dartbug few days ago (num 4652).